# JavaScript Being Called

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, mysqli

So I have a ajax function which appends data to a php page.  It works like a comment panel that when you scroll to the bottom you can click a button and it loads more comments.  This is the ajax function which loads more comments.

```
$("#loadmorecomments").click(function(){

 $('div#loadmorecomments').show();
  .ajax({
      url: "loadmorecomments.php?lastComment=" + $(".post:last").attr("id") + "&sname=<?php echo $link ?>",
            success: function(html){
                  if(html){
                    $("#postspace").append(html);
                    $("div#loadmorecomments").hide();

                     else{
                        ("div#loadmorecomments").replaceWith("div#done");
                    }
                });

});
```

This is the page it appends to the original php page. All of this code including the javacript is part of the loadmorecomments.php which gets appended to the original page.  So on the original page where all of this exact same code works.  Doesn't work on these new comments that are appended on.

```
 if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "SELECT post.text,post.username,post.id,post.likes,post.dislikes,post.image,users.avatar FROM post LEFT JOIN users ON post.username = users.username WHERE post.school='$sname' AND post.id < $lastcomment ORDER BY post.id DESC LIMIT 0,10")){
                               mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                               mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
                               mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$comments,$user, $id,$likes,$dislikes,$image,$avatar);
                                   $counter = 0;
                                   while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){


                                     /////////////////Get Image///////////////////
                                            switch($user){
                                                case "Anonymous":
                                                        $img = "design/anonymous.png";
                                                        break;
                                                case $user != "Anonymous" && !empty($avatar):
                                                        $img = $avatar;
                                                        break;
                                                case $user != "Anonymous" && empty($avatar):
                                                        $img = "logo.png";
                                                        break;
                                                }
                                            if(!empty($image) || $image != "images/"){
                                                $comimage = $image;
                                            }else{
                                                $comimage = ""; 
                                            }

                                                   echo "<div class = 'post' id = '$id'>";

                                        echo "<a href = './visitpage.php?userpage='$user'>$user<br /><img src='$img'/></a>";
                                        if(!empty($comimage)){
                                            echo "<img src='$comimage' class='comimage'></img>
                                                    <h3>$comments</h3>
                                                  ";

                                        }else{
                                            echo "<p>$comments</p>";
                                        }

                                        echo "<div style='border: 2px solid #000; height: 40px; margin-right: 20px; margin-left:90px; background: #F1F2F6'class='commentpanel' id='commentpanel_$id'>";
                                        if(in_array($id, $likedcomments)){
                                            echo "<img src='design/liked.png' class='like' /><h4 class='liketext' id='liketext_$id'>You and $likes</h4>";   

                                        }else{
                                            echo " <a href='' id='like_$id'><img src='design/like.png' class='like' /></a><h4 class='liketext' id='liketext_$id'>$likes</h4>";
                                        }
                                        if(in_array($id, $dislikedcomments)){
                                            echo "<img src='design/disliked.png' class='like' /><h4 class='liketext' id='liketext_$id'>You + $dislikes</h4>";   

                                        }else{
                                            echo " <a href='' id='dislike_$id'><img src='design/dislike.png' class='like' /></a><h4 class='liketext' id='liketext_$id'>$dislikes</h4>";
                                        }


                                        $link = urlencode($sname);
                                        echo  "
                                               <a href= '' id ='toggle_$id'><img src='design/reply.png' class='like'/><h4 class='liketext'>Send Message</h4></a>
                                              <a href= './quote.php?text=$comments&school=$link' ><img src='design/quote.png' class='like'/><h4 class='liketext'>Quote Post</h4></a>

                                              </div>

                                               <div class = 'replypost' id='replypost_$id'>
                                                <form action='' method='POST'>
                                                    <input type= 'hidden' name='user' id='user' value='$user' />
                                                    <input type= 'hidden' name='comment' id='comment' value='$comments' />
                                                    <input type='textarea' name='reply' id= 'reply' class='replycomment' />
                                                    <input type= 'submit' id='submit' name='submit' value=' Reply ' class='replybutton' />
                                                </form>
                                              </div>



                                                <br/><br/><br/>
                                             </div>";

                                        $counter++;
                                    }

                                    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

                           }

                                    mysqli_close($mysqli);
                           }
```

?>

```
                    <script><!---- Load More Comments !---->

                                $("#loadmorecomments").click(function(){

                                    $('div#loadmorecomments').show();
                                                        $.ajax({
                                                               url: "loadmorecomments.php?lastComment=" + $(".post:last").attr("id") + "&sname=<?php echo $link ?>",
                                                               success: function(html){
                                                                   if(html){
                                                                       $("#postspace").append(html);
                                                                       $("div#loadmorecomments").hide();

                                                                   }else{
                                                                        $("div#loadmorecomments").replaceWith("div#done");
                                                                   }
                                                               }
                                                     });

                        });


                            $("a[id ^= 'toggle']").click(function(event){

                                            event.preventDefault();
                                            $("div [id='replypost_"+$(this).attr('id').replace('toggle_','')+"']").toggle();

                                });

                            var likecounter = 0;
                            var dislikecounter = 0;

                            $("a[id ^= 'like_']").click(function(event){
                                    event.preventDefault();

                                    var value = $(this).attr("id").replace('like_','');
                                            $.ajax({
                                                               url: "./like.php?id="+value+"&sname=<?php echo $link ?>",
                                                               success: function(html){
                                                                   if(html && likecounter == 0 && dislikecounter == 0 ){

                                                                       $("#commentpanel_"+value).append("<br/><br/><br /><br /><h4>You Like This Post</h4>");
                                                                       likecounter = 1;

                                                                   }else{
                                                                        $("div#loadmorecomments").replaceWith("div#done");
                                                                   }
                                                               }
                                                     });


                                });

                            $("a[id ^= 'dislike_']").click(function(event){
                                    event.preventDefault();

                                    var value = $(this).attr("id").replace('dislike_','');
                                            $.ajax({
                                                               url: "./dislike.php?id="+value+"&sname=<?php echo $link ?>",
                                                               success: function(html){
                                                                   if(html && likecounter == 0 && dislikecounter == 0 ){

                                                                       $("#commentpanel_"+value).append("<br/><br/><br /><h4>You Hate This Post</h4>");
                                                                       dislikecounter = 1;


                                                                   }else{
                                                                        $("div#loadmorecomments").replaceWith("div#done");
                                                                   }
                                                               }
                                                     });


                                });




          </script>
```

I was wondering why when I click on the anchor tags that are suppose to call those javascript functions, it just refreshes the page and no javascript functions are called.

Note:  The original page has the exact same format of posting comments and calling the javascript functions and it works perfectly.  The only time it doesn't work is when the comments are loaded from the loadmorecomments.php file that is called.

I know this is a tricky question if I can clarify any further please just let me know thanks.

Comment: You're going to have much better luck getting an answer if you format your code reasonably.

Comment: Of what type is the element with the id `loadmorecomments`. From what I can gather from your code there seem to be two elements with that id. One you click, probably a button that appears nowhere in your linked source, and the div where you want to show the additional comments.

Comment: loadmorecomments is a <div> that shows a loading symbol but it is also the name of the php page loadmorecomments.php which contains the code to append more comments to the original page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I've realized the `live()` function is deprecated and about to be removed on version 1.9, so for everybody's sake I have edited my answer. you should be using the `on()` function instead. thanks!

---

ill try to explain this as best as i could.

as quoted from my comment..

"shouldn't you just use `live()` instead of `click()`? see the [API description](http://api.jquery.com/live/).. "**Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.**"

now, the question is.. what is the difference?

using `click()` would add the event handler to all the targets of the selector you specified in jQuery, it explains the 'NOW' on the API desctipion of `live()` earlier..

ex: `$("a[id ^= 'toggle']")` would apply only to all the DOM objects when that function was called.

so all the new objects inserted into the DOM wouldn't have that 'event handler'

but unlike `live()`, all the objects that would match the original selector would still be bound by the event you added, explaining the 'now and in the future' clause of the description.

in other words, it is like calling the same bind function, (in this case `click()`) every time a new object is inserted into the DOM that matches the original selectors..

so instead of the original

```
$("a[id^='toggle']").click(function(event){
```

you would be using

```
//$("a[id^='toggle']).live('click',function(event){ 
//EDIT: this is deprecated. use on() instead, see below:

$(document.body).on('click', 'a[id^="toggle"]', function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

recent post deleted.

New answer. I know it's not going to be that clean but try adding the `<!---- Load More Comments !---->` script in the `loadmorecomments.php` so it will be loaded when new comments were appended.

Comment: `$("a#dislike_")` and `$("a#like_")` will only match anchor tags with the exact IDs of dislike and like. OP is using the correct selector, `id^=` matches the exact start of an ID.

Comment: Yea that is why I am using that. This code works perfectly with the original comments that are loaded. It only stops working when the new comments are loaded with the loadmorecomments.php

Comment: ah. i miss interpret. sorry =)

Comment: Ah, @KeithDrakeWaggoner - that sounds like it's an issue with jQuery not seeing future elements being added to the DOM. Instead of `$("a[id^='toggle']).click()` try `$(document).on("click", "a[id^='toggle']", function(event) { });`

Comment: @Daniel Morris that would be a lot cleaner if that will work.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion unfortunately that didn't work.  For some reason these new comments are not being either identified by the java script or there is an error with the code. But i copied that code from the original page where it works perfectly so I don't know

Comment: what do you see in your firebug?

Comment: shouldn't you just use `live()` instead of `click()`? see the [API description](http://api.jquery.com/live/).. "Attach an event handler for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future."

Comment: @reikyoushin that you so much that is the correct answer I should have been using the live funcion. Can you maybe explain a little more clearly why. To help everyone who has been trying to figure this out.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell from the code snippets you've posted but I think you're saying that the second and third snippets are loaded via ajax. If so that is your problem as js (the third snippet) is not executed when loaded via ajax. The simplest solution is to include this javascript in your main js file and modify it so that it can deal with dom elements that have not yet loaded. You appear to be using JQuery so http://api.jquery.com/on/ has all the details you need if using JQuery 1.7+. If not, look at http://api.jquery.com/live/ which is even easier (but is tricky with iOS Safari).

Comment: Yes your are exactly write in that respect that the second and third snippets are loaded via ajax so I will need to fix that.  That javascript code is also on the original page that these snippets are loaded. So in that respect do I actually even need to bring that javascript code over again if the original page already has it?

Comment: No you don't but you do need to ensure that the javascript can deal with elements that are not yet loaded. The trick (whether using JQuery or something else) is to attach the event to a parent element that is always present (they will still receive the event unless you stop propagation) and then test in the event handler which element was originally clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting a `#` in the `href=""` attribute of the anchor tag which has the toggle ID. E.g. `<a href="#" id="toggle_$id"></a>`

Comment: I did try that. The page did not get refreshed but the javascript code also did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer came thanks to @reikyoushin I should be using the live() function to handle the click. Big thanks to everyone who attempted to help answer this question!!

Comment: sorry I was away for a little while I gave it to you. Thank you!